# 403 error on POST from react native to EC2 Spring Boot API

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, react-native, amazon-ec2

I have this spring boot app running on an AWS EC2 instance and when I make a post request from insomnia in my computer, it works, but, when calling it from my react native app, who's running in my mobile device, it gets a network error.
Facing this issue, I've got a postman-like app and made the request through to see what does it returns, then got a 403 error, with no body response attached.
May it be a missing inbound config on the EC2 instance?
Any help would be very welcome.

(The quoted "Postman-like")App request: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsZqN.png

Comment: Are you sure the headers on the requests are identical? If you post the two requests and the error, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: @Abe I've made an edit on the post and added a link for the image (can't add the image itself yet) and here's the insomnia request:
https://imgur.com/2xomhKe